# Как выглядит шорткод YITH WooCommerce Ajax product Filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

YITH WooCommerce search  вот так
 [yith_woocommerce_ajax_search]

Comment: Он выглядит точно так же как вы написали. В чем собственно заключается вопрос?

Comment: @eugene_v Думаю, реакции все равно не будет. Похоже, это очередной автор из серии "выстрелил вопросом и забыл" ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он никак не выглядит. Я скачал плагин и посмотрел его исходный код. Там нет определения шорткодов.

Comment: Я тоже смотрел код вчера, да и в документации ни слова ни полуслова о шорткоде

Comment: @eugene_v да, и в документации нет.

Answer (score 0):

**YITH WooCommerce Ajax product Filter** работает как виджет, если вы хотите его вывести в каком-то место, вам нужно вывести там кастомный сайдбар и в него положить уже виджет Фильтра

Comment: Он не об этом в заголовке спрашивает

Comment: Понял, это пятница вечер, оказывается все самое главное в заголовке